# Form Validation with PHP not working all if statements (debug help)

Tags: php, forms, validation, syntax-error, registration

I have my registration form but not all of my if statements are working. Please where is the bug I cant find that

```
$password    = ""; //Password
$password2   = ""; //COnfirm Password

 //Pass
$password = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password']); //Remove html tags
$password2 = strip_tags($_POST['reg_password2']); //Remove html tags

//This if is working and return error
if($password != $password2) {
    array_push($error_array, 'Your passwords do not match');
}
else{
    //This one is working as well
    if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $password)){
        array_push($error_array, 'Special characters like "£%^*() are not allowed');
    }
}

// I have the problem with this one. If user put 3 chars i don't get the error messages
// The form is not submitting but the error messages are not displayed
if(strlen($password) > 20 || strlen($password) < 5){
    array_push($error_array, 'Your password must be between 5 and 20 characters');
}

if(empty($error_array)){
    $password = md5($password); //Encrypt pass before send to db

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="reg_password2">Confirm Password</label>
       <input type="password" name="reg_password2" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="reg_password2"> 
          <span id="errorPassword2" class="text-danger"></span>
           <?php if(in_array('Your passwords do not match', $error_array)) 
                    echo '<span id="errorPass" class="text-danger">Your passwords do not match</span>';
                 else if(in_array('Special characters like "£%^*() are not allowed', $error_array)) 
                    echo '<span id="errorPass" class="text-danger">Special characters like "£%^*() are not allowed</span>';
                else if(in_array('Your password must be between 5 and 20 character', $error_array)) 
                    echo '<span id="errorPass" class="text-danger">Your password must be between 5 and 20 character</span>'; 
  ?>                             
  </div>
```

Everything is working proper except of the specific if option. But if the user put pass within the limit of 5-20 characters there's no problem with the registration.

Comment: Just tested your code. Everything looks good 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ae4124447b43479d39b74d648dfabc685682005

Comment: So, `var_dump(strlen($password))`

Comment: Observations ; Haven't initialized $error_array. and Php close tag is mised after the following statement if(empty($error_array)){ $password = md5($password); either u should closeit or you have to concatinate your markup in one of the php variable

Comment: Seriously, why add detail description to errors array and then __not output__ them?

Comment: typo :  characters   character

Comment: You check if the string `'Your password must be between 5 and 20 character'` is in your array, but if the string is >20 or <5 digits you add `'Your password must be between 5 and 20 characters'` with a 's' at the end. So the checking in your html can't find the string.

Comment: @JYoThI yes that stupid s was... Cheers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting this string if error occurred:

```
if(strlen($password) > 20 || strlen($password) < 5){
    array_push($error_array, 'Your password must be between 5 and 20 characters');
}
```

But when you want to show error message your are comparing this string:

```
else if(in_array('Your password must be between 5 and 20 character', $error_array)) 
                echo '<span id="errorEmail" class="text-danger">Your password must be between 5 and 20 character</span>';
```

So you are setting "characters" string and comparing with "character" string, if comparison isn't true

Comment: Thank you... I was looking for like 30 mins and thinking "Whats wrong everything is ok".. Lol thank you

Comment: np, these things happen :)

Answer (score 2):

**If u are f9 with jquery or js then u can implement using below code**

```
              function Validate()
  {
   var password = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("txtConfirmPassword").value;
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <input type="password" name="passwd" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"  required="required">
  <input type="password" name="rpasswd" id="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="repeatPassword" required="required" onChange="return Validate()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Side note: md5() is NOT a proper encryption. It creates only a hash.